RabbitMQ with Docker Compose: permission problems
I'm having some trouble with my deployment of RabbitMQ on Debian 12. This is the Docker Compose file I'm using:
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.12-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"   # RabbitMQ main port
      - "15672:15672" # RabbitMQ management UI port
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia:rw  # RabbitMQ database location
      - ./rabbitmq/log:/var/log/rabbitmq:rw  # RabbitMQ log location
      - ./rabbitmq/config:/etc/rabbitmq:rw  # RabbitMQ configuration location
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbitmqtest

I then use docker compose up. But the container stops immediatly and it gives me a permission error: touch: cannot touch '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf': Permission denied. This also happens when running docker logs rabbitmq.
I did make sure to add my user to the docker group using sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
An attempt to add the system user uid and gid to the docker compose file like this: USER: 1000:1000 also resulted in failure
After some hours of trying various different things (like creating the host directories manually to make sure they have the correct permissions), I have run out of things to try.

verify permission in your host "./rabbitmq/"  , data, log, config.   Also add RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER, RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS for management UI

Host directories data, log and config has chown as my system account. I added RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER and RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS to the Docker Compose file.

try  remove/comment your 3 volumes from docker-compose.  if works, you could try just once time with chmod -R 777 .rabbitmq/  in your host and add/uncomment your 3 volumes.
